# Can I press enter twice to execute a command?

Tags: shell, sh, zsh, iterm2

I'm using ZSH and I'm wondering if it's possible to map [enter, enter] to execute a command. Specifically, I'd like to move to my home directory when I press enter twice without typing any other text.

I don't want to make someone go through the trouble of writing me a script, but if any of y'all could point me in the right direction (zsh script/applescript/whatever it should be) and tell me if this is possible I'd really appreciate it!

I use iTerm2 on OSX, and zsh is my primary shell. Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Do you mean for both enters to be pressed on an empty line or only the second?

Comment: Either! But user1934428 answered my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at *preexec* in the section **SPECIAL FUNCTIONS** of the zsh manpage. If you define a function by this name, for instance in your .zshrc,  and you have the history mechanism enabled (as is common in interactive shells), this function receives as argument the command line you have entered. If you just typed *enter*, the command will be the null string. You can catch this and then do whatever you want - for instance doing a chdir.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.